AC works only on idle
I have a 2002 Ford Escape, six cylinders, 4WD. The air conditioner works great when I am going under 20 MPH. It works less between 20 and 40 MPH. After 40, it does not cool down at all. It has nothing to do with the engine temperature. When I am on the freeway at 70 MPH, the AC does not cool down. When I stop back to idle, the AC gets cold. I can't figure this out. Does anyone have an idea about what this can be?

If you have not had any AC service done recently, then it's likely low refrigerant. If you've recently had work done on the AC, then it could also be too much refrigerant. If the pressure is getting too high at highway speeds, this could trigger the cut-off switch.
Either way, you'll want to check your current pressure.

Thank you. It was the refrigerant. I had it checked, we added a small amount of refrigerant, and the AC is as cold as new.
